# Rational Functional Tester 8.5.1

Tags: java, rft

I'm using Rational Functional Tester(8.5.1) for recording applet based AWT application which developed in Oracle Forms. My problem is while recording it recognize only coordinate of x and y for example powerCARDBUSINESSDATE21JUN13Us().click(atPoint(377,263)); . I can't differentiate object in the AWT Application screen. Please help me as soon as possible.

My Environment :

Java 7
RFT 8.5.1 ( Trail Version )
Windows 7 Enterprise SP1

Answer (score 1):

In my case, testing a Java Application, I had to change the following Java setting (in Windows) to allow RFT to recognize the objects inside the Java Window Application :
Windows Start Icon --> Control Panel --> Java --> Advanded --> Java Plug-in --> UNCHECK "Activate the New Generation Java Plug-in"
Have Fun!.  ( ReStart )

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamilar with Oracle Forms.  Is it browser based?
If so, this IBM Knowledge Center article may help you.  It explains the requiements necessary for RFT to recognize Java Applets within a browser.  Note, that the Applet is recorded as a top level object in the Java Test Domain.  The fall back position, which is what you are seeing, is that RFT will just record coordinates.  My guess is you need to make sure you have satisfied the needed requirements in your browser for RFT to recognize the Applet.  Have a look.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSJMXE_8.3.0/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.doc/topics/Testing_Applets_in_HTML_Pages.html

I also found this, which lists RFT's nested domain support.  You can see if the domain nesting you require is listed.  The applet would be in the Java domain.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSJMXE_8.3.0/com.ibm.rational.test.ft.doc/topics/r_nested_domain_support.html